# Open File Dialogue missing a type of files

Tags: vb.net

I want user to upload a logo, for the same I created an `OpenFileDialog`. Everything works fine, but the dialog if opened more than once it doesn't show some type of files. When I checked it properly, I came to know that these files are of `.gif` type.

Here is my code -

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    With OpenFileDialog1
        Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        .CheckFileExists = True
        .Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png, *.bmp, *.gif) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png, *.bmp, *.gif"

        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

I will show you some images, so you will get a clearer idea about the issue.

**This is my control to open dialog**

[image]

**When I click it, File Dialog Opens and shows these many images**

[image]

**Now if I cancel or select any one of these images and open the file dialog again it doesn't show some files(`.gif`)**

You can see this in image below

[image]

At first I thought it is because I haven't added `*.gif` in my code to filter images. But even after adding it, facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separator changes & makes the filter invalid: `*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png, *.bmp, *.gif` should be `*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif`.

The filter is also being set after opening the file dialog the first time. Set the filter first & then call `ShowDialog()`:

```
With OpenFileDialog1
    .CheckFileExists = True
    .Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png, *.bmp, *.gif) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif"

    Dim result As DialogResult = .ShowDialog()

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Yeah it works. The separator was making the filter invalid. Thank You +1